# A Haskell Problem writing Error Found hole _ a5

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Make a function that counts the next element in the binary tree.

```
data BSearchTree a = Nil | Node a (BSearchTree a) (BSearchTree a)
                      deriving (Show, Eq)
successor :: (Ord a) => a -> BSearchTree a -> Maybe a 
successor a = if a Nil then Just succ Nil
              else if a (Node _ t1 t2)
               then Just succ a (Node _ t1 t2)
           else Nothing
```

Found hole: _ :: a5
      Where: ‘a5’ is an ambiguous type variable
    • In the first argument of ‘Node’, namely ‘_’
      In the first argument of ‘a’, namely ‘(Node _ t1 t2)’
      In the expression: a (Node _ t1 t2)
    • Relevant bindings include
        a :: a (bound at desktop/Aufgabe6.4.hs:32:11)
        successor :: a -> BSearchTree a -> Maybe a
          (bound at desktop/Aufgabe6.4.hs:32:1)
      Constraints include Ord a (from desktop/Aufgabe6.4.hs:30:1-53)
   |
 |               else if a (Node _ t1 t2)

don't really understand, what the error means...

Comment: The underscore (`_`) means it is still something you need to fill in. Holes are sometimes used to let Haskell derive the type of that hole (and to give partial solutions :) )

Comment: You are trying to use `if` to do pattern matching, but `if` does not do pattern matching. You need to use `case a of ....` or multiple defining equations.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, there are two underscores (`_`) at the right side of the `successor` function, these are [*typed holes* [haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes).

Typed holes are useful to let the compiler generate the type of the item that should be placed there, if it is hard to figure this out yourself. On QA sites, like StackOverflow, typed holes are frequently used to provide a solution where the OP still needs to implement certain aspects.

In this specific case, you will thus need to fill in some expression for the `_` in the two subexpressions `(Node _ t1 t2)` (not per se the *same* expression in the two cases).

Comment: I don't think there's anything you could fill these holes in with to make the program compile. Calling `a` as a function just makes no sense no matter what arguments you construct for it.

Answer (score 4):

```
if a (Node _ t1 t2)
```

This is not valid Haskell.  You seem to be treating `if` as a place to pattern match when in fact it requires a boolean expression.

```
if a Nil then
```

This seems to be following the same logic.

Instead consider pattern matching via a case expression or function definition:

```
successor :: (Ord a) => a -> BSearchTree a -> Maybe a 
successor _NotUsingThisValue Nil = ... something ...
successor valToMatch (Node val leftTree rightTree) = .. other thing ..
```

N.B. `Just succ Nil` is also not valid.  First, it parses as `(Just succ) Nil` (not `Just (succ Nil)`) and secondly there is no meaningful use of `succ` here.

Answer (score 0):

In Haskell, `if` statements work on `Bool` values. In your program, you have syntax that looks like `if (a Nil) then ... else ...`. Unfortunately, `(a Nil)` is not a `Bool` value. In fact, `a Nil` is not a well typed value at all.

So, one way to write your code is the way Thomas M. DuBuisson said. Another way is to use `case ... of ...` syntax.

```
successor :: (Ord a) => a -> BSearchTree a -> Maybe a 
successor a = case a of
                Nil -> Just (succ Nil)
                n@(Node _ t1 t2) -> Just (succ a n)
                _ -> Nothing
```

Couple of other comments:

- Note the use of `n@(Node _ t1 t2)` above. This says "remember anything that matches this pattern as `n`". Writing `Just (succ a (Node _ t1 t2))` on the right hand side of the pattern would not work, because `(Node _ t1 t2)` is a pattern, not a value, i.e, it is an instruction to match the `BSearchTree a` values of that "shape".
- Every value of type `BSearchTree a` always matches `Nil` or `Node _ _ _`. This is guaranteed by the Haskell semantics. Therefore, you should not really need the `else Nothing` branch.
- You can write `case a of Nil -> ... ; _ -> ...` as `if (a == Nil) then ... else ...`, but this is not advisable.